# What is the proper syntax of Java's lastIndexOf and indexOf when validating data?

Tags: java, string

e have a date form that can accept 2 or 4 digit years. I am not trying to code for exceptions...just instances where the year is either 2 or 4 digits long. I'm using lastIndexOf to find the last instance of "/", and if the third character after the slash is numeric, I assume a 4-digit year. Otherwise it's a two digit year.

I've already tested and validated that this is the only line giving me an issue right now,

```
if (inputLine.lastIndexOf.isNumeric("/"))+3 {
   year = inputLine.trim().substring(inputLine.lastIndexOf("/")+1,input.lastIndexOf("/")+4).trim);
   else year = "0000";
```

I keep getting compilation errors. For the lines in which I'm adding to the index Value,  I've got a `bad operand for the binary operator`. Additionally, the variable lastIndexOf can't be found.

I'm calling the list below at the head of the program, and as far as I can tell from the java documentation, `io` and `lang` pull in the appropriate methods and classes.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.lang.*;
```

For the `if` statement, although my parens are *balanced*, I don't know if adding the additional characters (e.g., index value + 3) is being done within the right level of the nested parens. That being said, I've tried top add those integers pretty much to no avail.

```
if (inputLine.lastIndexOf.isNumeric("/"))+3 {
   year = inputLine.trim().substring(inputLine.lastIndexOf("/")+1,input.lastIndexOf("/")+4).trim);
   else year = "00/00/0000";
```

I'm wondering a couple thigs: First, can I do this in a single statement, or is it better to define the index in one statement, then define index+offset-value in a subsequent statement?

When I'm using multiple methods and classes operating on a single field (e.g., `.trim().substring.Indexof()` etc., what is the order in which Java parses those? I'd like to undestand how these statements are being parsed so I've got a better understanding of the best way to manipulate the variables and test the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the +3 incorrectly.  You're putting it outside of the if(condition) statement, somewhere where it doesn't make any syntactic sense - it's gobbledygook in your code.

Also, if you're trying to test if the result of inputline.lastIndexOf('/') is numeric, it won't mean anything.  If the specified character does not occur, lastIndexOf won't throw an exception; it will just return -1.  You want to test if the result is greater than/equal to zero.

Comment: So if I get what you're saying, `if (inputLine.lastIndexOf("/")+3)>2)` will work...the assumption is that no instances of `/` will give me a -1, add three to get 2, so a TRUE condition would exists with a value of 3+. I think my logic is sound, but fuzzy on the syntax...and if I've got the +3 in the right place now...

Comment: That is correct.  I'm not sure why you feel the need to add 3 though.

Comment: The field I'm evaluating can have date strings formatted as `01/23/12` or `01/23/2012`. I'm testing that if the THIRD digit after the LAST instance of `\` exists to determine if the date is a 2 or 4 digit year. By adding 3 to the index of `\` I retrieve a null value (in the case of `/12`) or a `1` (in the case of `/2012`. Is that sound reasoning? or is there a better way?

Comment: Adding 3 to the return value of inputLine.lastIndexOf("/") won't return any other value, not unless you use something such as inputLine.charAt (in which case, if you give an index greater than or equal to the length, it will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, not return null).  If your date strings are formatted such that the month and day ALWAYS take two characters each (01 instead of 1, 09 instead of 9), why not just check if inputLine.length() returns a value equal to 8 (for 2-digit years) or 10 (for 4-digit years)?  Keep the if statement to check if there is a last slash at all.

Comment: Aha. That makes sense. Forgot about `length()`. Thanks loads!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use trim() and then use an index from the original string.  You need to trim() the string and then use an index from the trimmed string (otherwise the index could be completely incorrect)

Perhaps using SimpleDataFormat with a `dd/MM/yyyy` format or using split would be a better choice.

```
String[] parts = inputLine.trim().split("/");
String day = parts[0], month = parts[1], year = parts[2];
```

To use trim() and lastIndexOf()

```
String trimmed = inputLine.trim();
int last = trimmed.lastIndexOf("/");
year = trimmed.substring(last+1);
```

Comment: Bingo...that gets to my question about the order in which things are processed. I thought how it was written is to trim, then pull the substring from the trimmed value based on index of the trimmed field. How is that bing interprete, then?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the last part of your question

When you do method chaining like `.trim().substring.Indexof()` each method is invoked in left-to-right order.  So:

```
String myString = " string ";
int index = myString.trim.substring(3).indexOf('n');
```

is the comparable to:

```
String myString = " string ";
String trimmedString = myString.trim(); // "string"
String subString = trimmedString.substring(3) // "ing"
int index = subString.indexOf('n'); // 1
```

Comment: Exaclty what I was hoping for. That'll help me track down what's going on part-by-part. Thanks!